# Vuejs 2 v-if directive not rendered after catching event triggered by child component

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm using vuejs 2.0 and laravel 5.3. I'm emitting a custom event from a child component (a typeahead component) and I'm catching this event by using v-on directive.

Here is the code of my component :

```js
<template>
    <input ref="input" class="typeahead-suggestions"
           :class="classes"
           :id = "id"
           v-bind:value="value"
           v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"
           v-on:blur="formatValue"
           :placeholder="placeholder">
</template>
<script>
    var Bloodhound = require('typeahead.js')
    export default {
        data: function() {
            var id =  'typeahead-suggestion' + parseInt(Math.random() *100000);
            return {
                id,
                defaultSuggestions: [],
                query: ''
            };
        },
        props: {
            param: {
                type: String,
                default: 'item'
            },
            value: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            classes: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            displayKey: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            suggestionTemplate: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                default: 'Vue Auto Complete'
            },
            prefetch: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            defaultSuggestion: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            remote: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            local: {
                type: Array,
                default: function () {
                    return [];
                }
            },
            responseWrapper: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            }
        },
        watch: {
            local: function(newVal) {
                if (this.defaultSuggestion) {
                    this.defaultSuggestions = [...newVal];
                }
                this.resetTypeahead();
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.initTypeahead();
            if (this.local.length) {
                this.defaultSuggestions = [...this.local];
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateValue: function (value) {
                this.$emit('input', value);
            },
            formatValue: function () {
                this.$refs.input.value = this.value;
            },
            transformer: function (response) {
                if (this.responseWrapper) {
                    response = response[this.responseWrapper];
                }
                if (this.defaultSuggestion && this.local.length === 0) {
                    this.defaultSuggestions = response.splice(0, 5);
                }
                return response;
            },
            bloodhoundOption: function() {
                var bloodhoundConfig = {};
                if (this.prefetch) {
                    var prefetch = {
                        cache: false,
                        url: this.prefetch
                    };
                    if (this.defaultSuggestion) {
                        prefetch = {...prefetch, transform: this.transformer};
                    }
                    bloodhoundConfig = { prefetch};
                }
                if (this.local) {
                    bloodhoundConfig = {
                        local: this.local,
                        ...bloodhoundConfig
                    }
                }
                if (this.remote) {
                    bloodhoundConfig = {
                        remote: {
                            url: this.remote,
                            wildcard: '%QUERY',
                            transform: this.transformer
                        },
                        ...bloodhoundConfig
                    }
                }
                return bloodhoundConfig;
            },
            parseTemplate: function(data) {
                var res = Vue.compile(this.suggestionTemplate);
                var vm = new Vue({
                    data,
                    render: res.render,
                    staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
                }).$mount();
                return vm.$el;
            },
            getSource: function() {
                var self = this;
                var bloodhoundConfig = this.bloodhoundOption();
                var datumTokenizer = this.displayKey ? Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(this.displayKey)
                                                    :  Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace;
                var engine = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer,
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    ...bloodhoundConfig
                });
                var source = function(q, sync, async) {
                    if (q === '' && self.defaultSuggestions.length>0 && self.defaultSuggestion) {
                        sync(self.defaultSuggestions);
                    } else {
                        engine.search(q, sync, async);
                    }
                };
                return this.defaultSuggestion ? source : engine;
            },
            resetTypeahead: function() {
                $(document).find('#' + this.id).typeahead('destroy');
                this.initTypeahead();
            },
            initTypeahead: function() {
                var self =  this;
                var templates = {};
                if (this.suggestionTemplate) {
                    templates = {suggestion: self.parseTemplate}
                };
                var dataset = {
                    name: 'Typeahead-Suggestion',
                    display: this.displayKey,
                    source: this.getSource(),
                    templates
                };
                $(document).find('#' + self.id).typeahead({
                    minLength: 0,
                    highlight: true
                }, dataset)
                .on('typeahead:select', function(event, suggession) {
                    self.$emit('input', self.displayKey? suggession[self.displayKey]: suggession);
                    self.$emit('selected', suggession);

                    // Set value of hidden input to the id of selected item
                    $('input[name="' + self.param + '"]').attr("value", suggession['id']);

                    self.$emit(self.param + '_typeahead');
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the above code I emit a custom event after typeahead selection is done ('typeahead:select') by the following statement:

```
self.$emit(self.param + '_typeahead');
```

Here is my root vue instance :

```js
var typeahead = require('./components/typeahead.vue');

if (formElm = document.getElementById('form')) {

    new Vue({
        el: "#form",
        data: {
            form: new Form(formElm),
            initialData: (typeof initialData !== 'undefined') ? initialData : [],
            categories: (typeof categories !== 'undefined') ? categories : [],
            parents: (typeof parents !== 'undefined') ? parents : []
        },
        components: {
            'typeahead': typeahead
        },
        mounted() {
            if (typeof initialData !== 'undefined') {
                for (let field in initialData) {
                    this.form[field] = initialData[field];
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onSubmit() {

                // get all the fields
                let formData = this.form.data();
                let form     = this.form;
                let formInfo = form.info(formElm);

                // setup the constraints for validate.js
                var constraints = {
                    name: {
                        presence: {
                            message: "is required."
                        }
                    },
                    description: {
                        presence: {
                            message: "is required."
                        }
                    },
                    category_id: {
                        presence: {
                            message: "is required."
                        }
                    }
                };

                // validate the fields
                validate.async(formData, constraints)
                        .then(function(success) {
                            if (formInfo['method'] == 'PUT') {
                                form.put(formInfo['url']);
                            } else {
                                form.post(formInfo['url']);
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            form.onFail(error);
                        });
            },

            onSuccess(response) {
                form.reset();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the following is my blade template where I use this component :

```html
            <form method="post" id="form" action="{{ url('admin/eventType') }}" @submit.prevent="onSubmit"
                  @keydown="form.errors.clear($event.target.name)">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" v-model="form.name" placeholder="Name">
                    <span class="help text-danger" v-if="form.errors.has('name')" v-text="form.errors.get('name')"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" v-model="form.description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                    <span class="help text-danger" v-if="form.errors.has('description')" v-text="form.errors.get('description')"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category_id">Category</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="category_id" name="category_id" v-model="form.category_id" />
                    <typeahead v-on:category_id_typeahead="form.errors.clear('category_id')" param="category_id" :default-suggestion="true" :local="categories" display-key="value" classes="form-control">
                    </typeahead>
                    <span class="help text-danger" v-if="form.errors.has('category_id')" v-text="form.errors.get('category_id')"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="parent_id">Parent</label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="parent_id" name="parent_id" v-model="form.parent_id" />
                    <typeahead param="parent_id" :default-suggestion="true" :local="parents" display-key="value" classes="form-control">
                    </typeahead>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" :disabled="form.errors.any()">Create New Event Type</button>
            </form>
```

In the template above I catch the event in the component tag by v-on directive :

```
<typeahead v-on:category_id_typeahead="form.errors.clear('category_id')"
           param="category_id" :default-suggestion="true"
           :local="categories" display-key="value"
           classes="form-control">
```

The Problem : I'm using a v-if directive that decides on displaying an  error text based on output of a method :

```
<span class="help text-danger" v-if="form.errors.has('category_id')" v-text="form.errors.get('category_id')"></span>
```

Since triggering the 'category_id_typeahead' clears the error for this field, the output of the form.errors.has('category_id') method should be false so the error should be removed but it does not. According to what I print by console.log the error object does not contain the error for this field after triggering the event but the text is not removed until another change is made to the form. It seems like the v-if is not rendered at this step.

Here is the code of my form class :

```js
const formToJSON = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    if (!['submit'].includes(element.type) && !['_token'].includes(element.name)) {
        data[element.name] = element.value;
    }
    return data;
}, {});

const formInfo = elements => [].reduce.call(elements, (data, element) => {
    if (['_method'].includes(element.name)) {
        data['method'] = element.value;
    }
    if (typeof initialData !== 'undefined' && data['method'] == "PUT") {
        data['id'] = initialData['id'];
    }
    return data;
}, {});

// get entity
const currentEntity = function() {
    url           = window.location.href;
    adminPosition = url.indexOf('admin/') + 6;
    entity        = url.substring(adminPosition, url.indexOf('/', adminPosition));

    return entity;
}

class Errors {
    constructor() {
        this.errors = { };
    }

    has(field) {
        console.log('has error field : ', field, ' => ', this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field));

        return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
    }

    any() {
        return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
    }

    get(field) {
        if (this.errors[field]) {
            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }

    record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    clear(field) {
        if (field) {
            console.log('Before : clear error of ', field, ' error:', this.errors[field]);
            delete this.errors[field];

            return;
        }

        this.errors = {};
    }
}

class Form {
    constructor(formElm) {
        // get form data
        data = formToJSON(formElm.elements);

        this.originalData = data;

        for (let field in data) {
            this[field] = data[field];
        }

        this.errors = new Errors();
    }

    info(formElm) {
        data   = formInfo(formElm.elements);
        entity = currentEntity();
        if (data['method'] == 'PUT') {
                data['url'] = '/admin' + '/' + entity + '/' + data['id'];
        } else {
                data['url'] = '/admin' + '/' + entity;
        }

        return data;
    }

    data() {
        let data = {};
        for (let property in this.originalData) {
            var propertyValue  = document.getElementById(property);
            if (typeof propertyValue !== 'undefined' && propertyValue.value !== null &&
                propertyValue.value !== "") {
                data[property] = propertyValue.value; 
            } else if (typeof initialData !== 'undefined' &&
                       typeof initialData[property] !== 'undefined') {
                data[property] = initialData[property];
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    reset() {
        for (let field in this.originalData) {
            this[field] = '';
        }

        typeaheads = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="typeahead"]');
        for (let item in typeaheads) {
            typeaheads[item].value = '';
        }

        this.errors.clear();
    }

    post(url) {
        return this.submit('post', url);
    }

    put(url) {
        return this.submit('put', url);
    }

    submit(requestType, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios[requestType](url, this.data())
                 .then(response => {
                     this.onSuccess(response.data);
                     resolve(response.data);
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                     this.onFail(error.response.data);
                     reject(error.response.data);
                 });
        });
    }

    onSuccess(data) {
        this.reset();
    }

    onFail(errors) {
        this.errors.record(errors);
    }
}

module.exports = Form;
```

How should I solve this problem ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You try to react on a change in a complex ojbects (Form) attribute.
Vue adds getter and setter to properties which trigger (UI) updates.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

In your case the update somewhere in the Form Update does not notify the view to perform a render update.

You should let  `v-on:category_id_typeahead="form.errors.clear('category_id')"` call a separate method whick performs `form.errors.clear('category_id');` and something that triggers a ui update. This could be https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate or a new `data:{showError:false...` attribute that gets changed.